# where is the FileSystem disk method?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In [Pharo By Example 2](http://www.deepintopharo.com/) there is this line of source code:

```
| working |
working := FileSystem disk workingDirectory.
```

However, `FileSystem browse` does not have a disk method when you navigate to the `all` aspect.

[image]

So how can I find out about the `disk` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention, you are browsing instance methods, while `disk` is a class method. To browse class methods you have to select a checkbox labeled **Class side** which is located below the list of classes.

Also if you want to find an implementation of a method, you can select it and press *Cmd + m* (or Ctrl on windows, or Alt on Linux), also this option is available in context menu under *Extended search... > implementors of it*. This will show you a list of implementation of this method. Another shortcut is to press *Shift + Enter*, this will bring a Spotlight which accepts class names, method names, etc.. and shows you the implementation